# Discrepency in 25th percentile of standard deviation calculation

Tags: pandas, statistics, python-3.x, sampling

For each of the following sample sizes [3,5,7,9], I Need to calculate the 25th percentile of the standard deviation for the values sampled. And the total number of trials will be 10.

**DataFrame**

```
US    China  Korea   India   UK
196    213    9        77    84
105    122   16        52    60
346    305  -12        78    69
155    113  -27        42    30
210    200  -5         68    65
212    190  -10        70    62
227    219  -4         90    87
106     96  -9         89    81
367    326  -11        91    80
86     104   21        69    83
200    194   -3        77    75
```

**My code:**

```
    sample_sizes = [5, 7, 9]
    num_trials = 10
    col_index = 3
    p = 25
    df=pd.read_csv(filename)
    std_list=[]
    for i in sample_sizes:
        for j in range(num_trials):
            Sample=df.sample(n=i, random_state=j)
            col=Sample.iloc[:,col_index].std()
            std_list.append(col)
        ptile=np.percentile(std_list,p)
        print(ptile)
```

The code above gives the following ptile values:

```
   9.079918996054708
   9.408029717257989
   11.572161922408418
```

However, if I do remove the first loop and hardcode the value for sample size the `ptile` value changes.

```
    num_trials = 10
    col_index = 3
    p = 25
    df=pd.read_csv(filename)
    std_list=[]
    for j in range(num_trials):
        Sample=df.sample(n=7, random_state=j)
        col=Sample.iloc[:,col_index].std()
        std_list.append(col)
    ptile=np.percentile(std_list,p)
    print(ptile)
```

```
The code above gives `ptile = 11.878249130348483` for sample size 7 
whereas the first code gives `ptile = 9.408029717257989` for a sample size of 7.
```

I will greatly appreciate it if someone can explain the reason for this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you forget to reset `std_list` after starting with a new sample size. With the following change to the first version of your code (the one with varying $i$), you get the desired results:

```
sample_sizes = [5, 7, 9]
num_trials = 10
col_index = 3
p = 25
df=pd.read_csv(filename)
for i in sample_sizes:
    std_list=[]
    for j in range(num_trials):
        Sample=df.sample(n=i, random_state=j)
        col=Sample.iloc[:,col_index].std()
        std_list.append(col)
    ptile=np.percentile(std_list,p)
    print(ptile)
```